# When I click a link(name of a place) it should display the location in map on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary

When I click the link, I want to show the location on map on the same page. I've already integrated the map through my API key on my webpage. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
        <?php
            $add = "Amity University, Lucknow";
            $link = "http://maps.google.com/?q=".$add;
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Amity University, Lucknow</a>
        <script>
            function myMap() {
            var mapProp= {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
                zoom:5,
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4jChq2-_I4Dc0KSh3VI_OCaCDcG68oq8&callback=myMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't want the result on another page instead, I want the same map to move to the desired location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use the [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) (unless you have the coordinates of your "places").

```
function geocodeAddress(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == "OK") {
         if (results[0].geometry.viewport) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
         else if (results[0].geometry.bounds) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
         else map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else alert("geocoder failed, status: "+status);
    });
}
```

Then use it like this in your HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('Amity University, Lucknow');">Amity University, Lucknow</a> - 
<a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('London, UK');">London</a> - 
<a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('Oxford University');">Oxford</a>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/66wn358r/1/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('Amity University, Lucknow');">Amity University, Lucknow</a> -
<a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('London, UK');">London</a> - <a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('Oxford University');">Oxford</a>
<script>
  // global map variable
  var map;

  function myMap() {
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
      zoom: 5,
    };
    // initialize global map variable
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  }

  function geocodeAddress(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      address: address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == "OK") {
        if (results[0].geometry.viewport) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        else if (results[0].geometry.bounds) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
        else map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else alert("geocoder failed, status: "+status);
    })
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the coordinates from the api and reload the myMap function()

for Amity University-Lucknow, The coordinates are "26.8509922,81.0476597"

```
function myMap(x,y) {
        var mapProp= {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
            zoom:5,
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
```

And you should remove the href from "< a >" since it is changing the URL which in turn change the page.

UPDATE :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
    <a onClick="myMap(26.8509922,81.0476597)">Amity University, Lucknow</a>
    <script>
        function myMap(x,y) {
            if(x==undefined || y==undefined){
                x = 51.508742;
                y= -0.120850;
            }
        var mapProp= {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
            zoom:15,
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4jChq2-_I4Dc0KSh3VI_OCaCDcG68oq8&callback=myMap"></script>
</body>
```

You have to get the coordinates of your links from the gmaps and paste them on onClick(myMap({x,}{y}))

Comment: See I would've multiple links of different locations. and I want the map to search the link when clicked and display result within same div

Comment: @zainulabdeen check Update .. Its working without PHP